# Sorting functionality scandir function bug

Tags: php, sorting, scandir

I'm experiencing some unexpected behaviour with the scandir function. The documentation says it is sorting the files and folders default by ascending order. Now I have a folder with six files in it:

```
__Abstract.coffee
__Abstract.js
Copy.coffee
Copy.js
Delete.coffee
Delete.js
```

Now it appears to be that PHP's scandir output is most of the times:

```
array (
  0 => '.',
  1 => '..',
  2 => '__Abstract.coffee',
  3 => '__Abstract.js',
  4 => 'Copy.coffee',
  5 => 'Copy.js',
  6 => 'Delete.coffee',
  7 => 'Delete.js',
)
```

But sometimes (1 times in 50 or so) it puts the __Abstract.coffee and __Abstract.js at the end so the returned value is:

```
array (
  0 => '.',
  1 => '..',
  2 => 'Copy.coffee',
  3 => 'Copy.js',
  4 => 'Delete.coffee',
  5 => 'Delete.js',
  6 => '__Abstract.coffee',
  7 => '__Abstract.js',
)
```

Because of this the JS files are sometimes not loaded in the right order (it is a js packer/minifier script).

I know how to work around this with the sort functions, but that is not very efficient if the scandir function should order the files by itself. Is this a bug in the scandir function and should I report this in the php bugtracker or is it more like a filesystem/OS thing (I'm using a default LVM installation under CENTOS 6.3).

Can you guys please help me with some advice :-) thank you!

I have sent in a bugreport at PHP: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65709

Comment: Can you post the real `scandir()` call? You can force the ordering: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: @createproblem The call is `$aFolderContents = scandir($sPath);`. The $sPath variable holds the path to the directory. The manual of PHP states that the ordering is default set to SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING. I tried to add this explicitly in my code so it became `$aFolderContents = scandir($sPath, SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING);` But the problem persists.

Comment: I found out the problem is probably laying under the SORT_LOCALE_STRING sort. I added `sort($aFolderContents, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);` And this also randomly doesn't sort the array properly. The normal string comparision puts the underscore after the alphabet. It looks like the sort method doesn't always recognize which locale has been set (in my case NL_nl).

Comment: I had similar problems with sort stuff between Ubuntu and RedHat my solution was to set explicit the sort parameter. Can you please test the following snippet: https://gist.github.com/createproblem/6621289
Maybe this could solve you problem. For performance issues you can cache the data, its not the best but... :D

Comment: Awesome dude, SORT_LOCALE_STRING will solve my ugly issue too. So many constants to remember :D

Comment: I tried your snippet and the output is also differing from time to time. Also when I put the SORT_LOCALE_STRING in the sort function of your snippet it differs a lot. Just try it yourself by creating a file with two underscores at the beginning of the filename. If you refresh the output of the script for several times the sort order differs from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has something to do with the intl extension. When I disable it, the problem does not occure. It doesn't make a diffrence if the extension is installed with pecl or compiled using --enable-intl. I will catch up with the developers of the intl extension for the solution to this problem.